# E. coli, risk of infection?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, digestive-system, ecoli, infection

There has been a warning about E. coli contaminated water in South Florida. Now I'm wondering are there empirical data or historic cases which show a correlation between E.coli levels in tap water and risk of infection in the population drinking this water. Which pathogens, that could be transmitted through tap water, are common in this area?

Comment: This falls within personal medical advice which is off topic as per the FAQ. If you can remove the references to yourself (can a glass washed with warm E coli contaminated water pose a health risk, or better yet, what is the max temperature at which infectious E coli survive), it might be answered, but it's still borderline.

Comment: You will know shortly. ;-)

Comment: @dd3 Ok as changed it.

Comment: I think there has been something of a misunderstanding here between E. coli and the risk of an infection. Normally E.coli is no pathogen, you have a lot of them in your intestines. The measuring of E. coli in tap water and food is a normal procedure to find faecal contamination, since E.coli is easy to grow. But there are other pathogens you have to worry about like Salmonella, Enterococcus, Cholera and also some E.coli. But it is to expensive to test for every possible pathogen. I'm trying to change you question, to what I think you want to know.

Comment: @NeoDevlin Your comment above would make the best answer currrently. Unfourtunately, there's no "Not a comment; Should be an answer instead." flag!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum temperature for *E. coli* to survive is dependent on the strain. *E. coli* from warm areas can easily survive 45 °C and more. The minimum number of *E. coli* to ingest in order to become ill is also dependent on the strain. Whether you become ill at all is also dependent on the strain. You harbor many billions of *E. coli* in your digestive tract without becoming ill, so without further information on the released strain, it's really hard to tell.

One of the suggestions from the [WHO Guidelines for drinking water quality](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/guidelines/en/) is to boil the water in order to desinfect it.

Answer (score 1):

One [textbook of microbiology](http://www.textbookofbacteriology.net/e.coli_4.html) suggests that the infectious dose of a specific strain of enterotoxigenic *E. coli* in adults would be $10^{8}$ cells. Keep in mind that infective dose will vary with species and strain, as well as the health, age and immune-status of the individual ingesting the bacteria. Children, elderly and ill people will generally be affected by a lower infective dose. This does also not consider how well the bacteria can colonize the gastrointestinal system. It is possible for minimal numbers of pathogenic *E. coli* to colonize in the gut, and only after growing to a infectious level, being to exert pathogenic effects.